# How to give button ID when calling a create button function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Please excuse my ignorance as I'm new to Python and am experimenting.

I am creating a dashboard that allows users to open a file. When a user opens a file, the software adds a row with the file name, progress bar and a few buttons all on the same row. The row creation is done by calling a function which increments the row value every time its called to ensure it doesn't replace the existing row but instead adds another row beneath it to represent the latest file opened by the user.

Lets say there are two rows on the dashboard with their respective file names and buttons. My problem is when I go to press the button on the first row, it thinks that I'm pressing the button on the second row simply because the counter is set to 2 when adding a second row and I am trying to identify which button the user is pressing by checking the row but am unable to do that due to the counter.

Is there anyway I can "bind" the row value to the button when declaring it when calling the create button function so that they keep some form of ID and I can tell which row the user is interacting with?

I have tried assigning the button an ID when calling the function to identify which button is being pressed and on what row, but the button gets overwritten on all rows when the function is called again.

I have also tried to check what button the user is pressing by checking the text of the button, but that also gets overwritten when the function is re-called regardless if the names of the buttons are different on the UI itself.

Any help is very much appreciated. Hopefully I was clear enough.

```
def OpenFile(self): # user opening file which creates row with button
        print("Opening")
        btnCreation(self)

def btnCreation(self): # function to create buttons dynamically
    incrementFunction(self)
    global EXEBtn
    EXEBtn = Button(Main_frame,
         text="Execute",
         width=8,
         command=self.Execute)
         EXEBtn.grid(row=RowCounter, column=2, padx=3)

def incrementFunction(self):
    global RowCounter 
    RowCounter = RowCounter + 1

def Execute(self):
    # check which row the execute button was pressed on to do something
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple and quick solution is just to give the function the current `RowCounter` value with a `lambda` expression like this:

```py
def btnCreation(self): # function that creates button dynamically
    incrementFunction(self)
    global EXEBtn
    EXEBtn = Button(Main_frame,
         text="Execute",
         width=8,
         command=lambda e=RowCounter: self.Execute(e))
         EXEBtn.grid(row=RowCounter, column=2, padx=3)
```

The specific change here is `command=lambda e=RowCounter.get(): self.Execute(e)`, changing the way the buttons command works. Basically it is creating a `lambda` expression that saves the value of `RowCounter`, which will be passed to the `Execute()` function when the button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I have just tried to implement your suggestion and am now getting the following error for that command change: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @Mike I changed the code, I thought you were using an `IntVar()` for `RowCounter` it should work now :).

You will have to have the `execute` function take the rowcounter as an input now, (e.g. `def Execute(self, rc):`

Comment: This isn't working for me yet - No error, but if I add two rows and press the button on the first row, it still thinks the row value is 2 when it's meant to be 1

Comment: Never mind I figured out what I was doing wrong, this is a great solution. Thank you very much for your assistance! It is appreciated